# If I build a game in Qt for Android and iOS can I include Objective-C toolkits in it like game center?

Tags: android, ios, qt

I want to build a game for both Android and iOS but I'm afraid I wont be able to make it fully functional as if I were to just build one in Objective-C. So can I use toolkits from Android and or iOS in Qt? or can I make it in Qt and add them in later with a different software?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand QT is a cross platform. It means that they got they own api for both Android and IOS. In android they use android-ndk so this mean you can't use android toolkit.

Look at [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/native-Android-discussion) they are speaking about it in the end of the page.

The only cross platform that I know that can do this is [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/il_en/products/air.html). I try it once. This a nightmare but it gives you the option to use android and ios native.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [V-Play](http://v-play.net/), a cross platform 2D game engine based on Qt. It offers [plugin components](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html#plugin-components) for Game Center, Facebook, ads and more.

More plugins are added constantly accordingly to developer requests.